# How to disable XT9 in a MultiAutoCompleteTextView screen

Tags: android

I have a MultiAutoCompleteTextView implemented on one of my screens. I was testing the application in various smartphones and when I tested in a smartphone that had XT9 turned on the texbox works, however when the word was selected in my textbox the XT9 does not clean the letters already typed, then when I started to type again the previous letters from the first word show up.

So I need to turn of XT9 in this screen or clean XT9 letters list. Someone knows how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that to disable the autocomplete of the Input I just needed to add the attribute `android:inputType="textAutoComplete"` on the MultiAutocompleteTextView's xml